# How to Know if Windows Defender is currently scanning

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-defender, windows-10-v1909

So my work laptop has been running hot all day with the Windows Defender service consuming a CPU core the whole time. A few restarts and a full shutdown haven't stopped it. Only thing I can think of is that our sysadmins kicked off a forced full system scan on all systems due to the recent Solarwinds hack. However, I can't see anything within the windows GUI to tell me if that's the case. Is there some place I can look to know if that's what's happening?

System is running Windows 10 1909 Build 18363.1256

Comment: see if it's helpful to you: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/protect/forum/protect_defender-protect_scanning-windows_10/how-do-i-know-if-defender-is-even-scanning-theres/90157f7f-4c3f-4600-a80d-4d17ca3c752d

Comment: Maybe just run Process Monitor and see what file IO is taking place.